# NotImplementedError at /

Tags: openstack

my local.conf file is:

```
[[local|localrc]]

HOST_IP=<MY IP>
SERVICE_HOST=$HOST_IP
MYSQL_HOST=$HOST_IP
RABBIT_HOST=$HOST_IP
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$HOST_IP:9292

ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

KEYSTONE_USE_MOD_WSGI="True"
NOVA_USE_MOD_WSGI="True"
SWIFT_USE_MOD_WSGI="True"
HEAT_USE_MOD_WSGI="True"
CINDER_USE_MOD_WSGI="True"



# ceilometer
enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer.git master

# horizon
enable_service horizon

# cloudkitty
enable_plugin cloudkitty https://git.openstack.org/openstack/cloudkitty.git master
enable_service ck-api ck-proc
CLOUDKITTY_COLLECTOR=ceilometer

disable_service tempest
```

after successfully completing `./stack.sh` I got this page instead of dashboard/login page
[image]

where is the issue?

****y downvoting men?? is this question not appropriate to ask in serverFault????????? or the error is not elobrated??
i have not straight away paster it here...i did tried different methods
if have have an intention to downvote please let me also know what is the reason to downvote so that I can also know what to ask and how its done**

Comment: The issue is in line 667 of the file `/opt/stack/horizon/horizontables/actions.py`.

Comment: ya..I did a research on that..got this "This issue was fixed in the openstack/horizon 9.0.0.0b3 development milestone." from https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1525309 .how to pull specific milestone? how to include it in local.conf file...Im working on it but could not figure out

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details

Answer (score 0):

i tried Cloudkitty with a normal installation process. I mean that i added it as a new openstack project. you can follow it on the openstack documentation. it worked perfectly for me with a Newton Openstack version. Sometimes, Horizon bugged for me when showing the rating service in the dashboard. I just reload Cloudkitty and ceilometer services to get back the rating service up. Honestly, i did not try a devstack installation. But, it seems that there is a missing configuration in at the Horizon level. i will try a devstack installation and if i get something i tell you.

Regards,